# Apache isis v1.15 repositoryService allInstances return incorrect size

Tags: mysql, apache, isis

I'm quite new to Apache ISIS, and I want to get a list via the dataNucleus with a legacy database(MYSQL)， There are 300,000 of the data, But when I'm trying to use  repositoryService.allInstances() method to get a List, returns the size of  list  is 2. I have other domain objects and those works fine.
here is the code and debug infos.

```
@PersistenceCapable(
    identityType = IdentityType.DATASTORE,
    schema = "public",
    table = "tinstruction_parameter_value"
)
@DatastoreIdentity(
    strategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY,
    column = "id")
@Queries({
    @Query(
            name = "find", language = "JDOQL",
            value = "SELECT "
                    + "FROM      domainapp.modules.simple.dom.impl.xfs.parameter.InstructionParameterValueTest "),
    @Query(
            name = "findByValueContains", language = "JDOQL",
            value = "SELECT "
                    + "FROM  domainapp.modules.simple.dom.impl.xfs.parameter.InstructionParameterValueTest "
                    + "WHERE value.indexOf(:value) >= 0 "),
    @Query(
            name = "findByValue", language = "JDOQL",
            value = "SELECT "
                    + "FROM      domainapp.modules.simple.dom.impl.xfs.parameter.InstructionParameterValueTest "
                    + "WHERE value == :value ")
})
@DomainObject(
    editing = Editing.DISABLED
)
@DomainObjectLayout(
    bookmarking = BookmarkPolicy.AS_ROOT
)
public class InstructionParameterValueTest implements      Comparable<InstructionParameterValueTest> {

@Column(allowsNull = "true",jdbcType = "CLOB")
@Property()
@MemberOrder(sequence = "10")
@Getter @Setter
private String value;

//region > compareTo, toString
@Override
public int compareTo(final InstructionParameterValueTest other) {
    return org.apache.isis.applib.util.ObjectContracts.compare(this, other,   "value");
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return org.apache.isis.applib.util.ObjectContracts.toString(this, "value");
}
//endregion

}

public class InstructionParameterValueTestRepository {

  @Programmatic
  public java.util.List<InstructionParameterValueTest> listAll() {
    return repositoryService.allInstances(InstructionParameterValueTest.class);
  }
}
```

[dataNucleus  debug log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63KFG.png)

I donot know why the size of the list is 2, not all datas, the debug sql can execute and get all datas.
[dataNucleus sql execute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJ6m6.png)
can anyone tell me what I should do,

Comment: Hmm, that seems very strange.  Can you post the code that iterates over the returned collection?  Looking at those queries I wonder why DN needs to submit any further queries at all; the data should be in its cache from the first query.  I see also that this table has clobs ... do the others that work also have clobs?   If you can provide some sort of test case on github to demonstrate the problem, that would help immensely.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply，my screenshot is the first query,The collection is displayed directly by wicket, I do not process the returned collection. I use the clobs field, because the database mysql field is tinytext, DN prompts me to use clobs, I am now on vacation, back to the company I try to change the other fields. Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: ok, so I think I'll need you to provide a test case on github for this.  thx

Comment: I'm sorry to have made a foolish mistake，my database connection address is wrong, I changed the database, but the address did not change,thank you very much for your reply！